# How to specify a specific folder for a NuGet source package?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, nuget

I am consuming a NuGet package source in my dotnet project:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>        
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Bcl.Json.Sources" Version="4.6.0-preview.19073.11">
      <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Source files are located in the `contentFiles` folder of the package, but are seen at the root folder of the project.
This is causing strange behaviours with existing files.

How can I specify a project folder location for this package ?

Comment: You fully answer to the question. Currently there is no way to control it if you are not the package owner. Thanks !
FYI, the NuGet package that was annoying  was updated by its owner and is now located in its own folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to specify a specific folder for a NuGet source package?

I am afraid there is no such way you can specify a project folder location for this package directly. Because this behavior is determined by the internal file structure of the package. If we are not the author/owner of this package, we could not change the internal file structure of the package.

As a workaround, you can download that nuget package and re-pack that package and change the target folder to `contentFiles/cs/netstandard2.0/Test/` with the `.nuspec` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata minClientVersion="2.12">
    <id>Microsoft.Bcl.Json.Sources</id>
    <version>4.6.0-preview.19073.11</version>
    <title>Microsoft.Bcl.Json.Sources</title>
    <authors>Microsoft</authors>
    <owners>microsoft,dotnetframework</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <licenseUrl>https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/LICENSE.TXT</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>https://dot.net/</projectUrl>
    <iconUrl>http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=288859</iconUrl>
    <description>Add Description Here</description>
    <releaseNotes>https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=799421</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.</copyright>
    <serviceable>true</serviceable>

    <contentFiles>
      <files include="cs/netstandard2.0/BitStack.cs" buildAction="content" flatten="true" copyToOutput="true"/>
      <files include="cs/netstandard2.0/xx.cs" buildAction="content" flatten="true" copyToOutput="true"/>
       ...
    </contentFiles>

  </metadata>

    <files>
      <file src="build/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.Bcl.Json.Sources.targets" target="build" />
      <file src="build/netstandard2.0/Strings.resx" target="build" />
      <file src="contentFiles/cs/netstandard2.0/BitStack.cs" target="contentFiles/cs/netstandard2.0/Test/" />
      <file src="contentFiles/cs/netstandard2.0/xx.cs" target="contentFiles/cs/netstandard2.0/Test/" />
      ...
    </files>

</package>
```

Then add this package to your [local nuget package feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52009642/installing-nuget-package-located-in-local-package-repository-into-a-new-visual-s), then use this your custom nuget package, all those `.cs` file are added to the `Test` folder:

[image]

Hope this helps.